# Can a web push notification launch a browser on click?

Tags: javascript, web, browser, push-notification

I'm currently studying about web push notif, and we are about to use it.
Ive search the web for the capabilities of push notif but I haven't found an answer to my question. Your inputs will be very much appreciated.
I simply want to open the browser (if closed) when the user clicks the push notification.

Comment: How will the user receive the push notification if the browser is closed to begin with?

Comment: I see..my bad ..thank you for answering..I suppose the push notif can open a new tab on click? @MattClark